# SAP HANA Cloud Platform for mobile apps

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-smp

Can the SAP HANA Cloud Platform be used to deploy mobile apps on its own?  Or do I require an on premise SMP Server etc.

I followed this tutorial https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?e7c9982cbb571014a97a8a675cf28c15.html and created an HTML5 Hello World application.

I don't see any options to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP HANA Cloud Platform allows you to deploy web and java applications. These are not mobile apps.
If your requirement is to create a mobile app (hybrid or native) you have to create it independently.

- You could use any platforms to create it - like SMP 3 or HCPms (SAP's mobile solution on cloud).
- Or you could create an app without these platforms using open source libraries - Odata, Cordova. But you have to get the enterprise level features to your app your own - and it's really hard.
- If you use a platform like SMP 3 or HCPms. It provides you everything you want. It has all enterprise level features inbuilt with it - encrypted storage, SSO, logging, troubleshooting, app life cycle management etc.
- It has an SDK for Hybrid and Native apps. You could use it to develop your apps.
- SDK trial and HCPms trial is available.
- The app you developed is a web applications (mentioned in your question). i.e you will be deploying this app to a server and access this app using a URL from anywhere, it could your laptop or your mobile devices.
- When you develop a hybrid or native app you don't need to deploy this app to a server. Instead you will be deploying this app to the devices. Ex. In the case of android app you will get an apk file and you will be deploying this to the devices.
- If you want to deploy these apps to multiple devices remotely you need to use an MDM solution like SAP mobile secure.