# Is there a solution to deploy SAP Mobile apps for Android without local SAP HAT installation?

Tags: sapui5, sap-smp, sap-web-ide

I am asking me if there is a way to deploy SAP hybrid apps (programmed in WEB IDE) for Android / iOS without having a "local" HAT connector installed?

My intention is that with all this cloud services it should be possible to consume a "build for Android" service in the cloud instead of installing the build stuff on a local developer machine.

This question is a little bit related with these posts:

- [SAP Mobile Integration with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470388/sap-mobile-integration-with-android)
- [SAP HANA Cloud Platform for mobile apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020936/sap-hana-cloud-platform-for-mobile-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this has been implemented end of last year. The prerequisites are as follows:

1. Subscribe to Portal service
2. Subscribe to Fiori Mobile service
3. Create a "default" launchpad in Portal service
4. Enable the Hybrid App Toolkit plugin in the WebIDE

Now when you create new apps in the WebIDE, on the first page there is a "mobile" checkbox that you need to select. If you have done this, you can trigger a cloud build via the "Fiori Mobile" context menu that you get when you right-click your project. You can find a more elaborate guide [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/27/hybrid-app-cloud-build-walkthrough-findings/).

Comment: . only it doesn't support offline odata

Comment: @AdamHarkus this is not entirely true - Offline has never really been supported by Fiori Mobile, as stated in the documentation, but the feature has been migrated to SAP Cloud Platform Mobile Services. [This blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/22/creating-an-offline-crud-hybrid-mobile-app-in-sap-web-ide-full-stack-with-hybrid-application-toolkit/) describes how to enable Offline with the new service.